# model class treated as local variable in django

Tags: python, django

When i tried to access the form for editing, this error occurs

```
local variable 'Profile' referenced before assignment
```

## views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect,get_object_or_404
from home.models import UserCreateForm,Profile
from home.forms import ProfileCreateForm


# Create your views here.

def update(request,pk):
    profiles=Profile.objects.all()
    print(profiles)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileCreateForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            Profile = form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = ProfileCreateForm(instance=profile_instance)
    return render(request, 'registration/profile.html', {'form': form})
```

the model is Profile

## models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
('M', 'Male'),
('F', 'Female')
    )
class Profile(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    dob = models.DateTimeField()
    profilePic = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstName
```

Adding new form works perfectly but accessing the saved form from the db results in an error

StackTrace
[image: Error Stacktrace]

Comment: Can you please share the full stacktrace and actual code which is throwing the error?

Comment: @ruddra Edited the question with stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had set form variable i.e. `Profile = form.save()` to `Profile` which is **Imported Model variable** you can't really use it other than pointing it to that particular model

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect,get_object_or_404
from home.models import UserCreateForm,Profile
from home.forms import ProfileCreateForm


# Create your views here.

def update(request,pk):
    profiles=Profile.objects.all()
    profile_instance = get_object_or_404(Profile, id=pk)   #<-- you must already have this
    print(profiles)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileCreateForm(request.POST,request.FILES, instance=profile_instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            abc = form.save()                                 # <-- Changes
            abc.save()                                        # <-- Changes
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = ProfileCreateForm(instance=profile_instance)
    return render(request, 'registration/profile.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

it worked

I thought save() shoud be called with help of model

Comment: Welcome and you can set any variable to `form.save()` method, just make sure its unique and no model variable and you're good to go. #happytohelp